# How do I fix "bad sectors" in my hard drive? (chkdsk didn't work)

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, backup, bad-sectors

I'm trying to run Acronis True Image to backup my disk and get this error:

[image]

I click ignore, my PC hangs for a while and then works normally and backup is completed.

I have tried almost everything I can: chkdsk, SeaTools (my HD is from SeaGate). Nothing worked and I still get the same error.

How can I fix the bad sector?

Comment: did you run `chkdsk /f`

Comment: @KaranGoel - You can't fix a bad sector.  If no other application can discover the bad sector, that would indicate, its a problem with Acronis.

Comment: Ditch Acronis.  It's a nightmare of bugs and totally unreliable.

Comment: @Keltari I did but it didn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound I reinstalled Acronis, but that didn't help. SeaTools did say that my disk has failed it's tests, I fixed using the tool but Acronis said there's still the same bad sector.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It don't know. Seems pretty good to me. I don't know of any better backup software.

Comment: @KaranGoel - If Sea Tools is saying your disk has failed test then your disk is due to be replaced. You cannot fix bad sectors on a hdd.  The duplicate question has a few tools that MIGHT be able the hdd reallocate those sectors but unlikely if you have S.M.A.R.T tests failing.

Comment: @KaranGoel - Look at the comments on Amazon -- http://www.amazon.com/review/R2B0ST3N04OMAO/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B009716UMA&nodeID=229534&store=software